# Change image of button when pressed, using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to set a value in variable when a specific button is pressed. I want this button to be in pressed state when i again reload the page. I am trying to check the value of variable in pageloaded function but i don't know that how can change the state of button in javascript. Pls help

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<button onclick="changeit()"><img src="bla.jpg" id="changevalue"></button>
```

**JS:**

```
function changeit(){

    document.getElementById("changevalue").src = "newimg.jpg";

}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply @RzelMz. I have tried it and working fine but not showing the new image of the button. I have used the complete src image path but all in vain. Pls help

Comment: You mean when the page is reloaded, it's the old picture? For this you maybe need to create a Session with php

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<button id="myButton"><img src="myImage.jpg" id="myImage"></button>
```

**JS:**

```
var NEW_IMAGE_URI = "myNewImage.jpg";
var buttonState = false;

function changeButtonImage(){
   if (buttonState) {
    return;
   }
   document.querySelector("#myImage").src = NEW_IMAGE_URI;
   buttonState = true; 
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var buttonElement = document.querySelector('#myButton');
    buttonElement.addEventListener('click',changeButtonImage); 
});
```